# overflow-y for ul, scroll down the list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a problem with my menu. I only want four menu items to appear at any time, meaning that if there’s an overflow, it’ll be clipped, and the user will have to scroll down.

I tried setting `overflow-y`, hoping to see it get clipped, but instead, a horizontal scroll bar appears.

### HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='http://donysukardi.com/ltw/css/blueprint/screen.css' type="text/css" media="screen, projection" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href='http://donysukardi.com/ltw/css/blueprint/print.css' type="text/css" media="print" /> 

<div class="container">
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" id="profile">profile</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#!profile/overview.html" id="overview">overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="partners">partners</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#!profile/partners/lim.html" id="lim">Lim Hong Lian</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!profile/partners/teo.html" id="teo">Teo Su Seam</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!profile/partners/marina.html" id="marina">Marina Baracs</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="associates">associates</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#!profile/associates/yang.html" id="yang">Jocelyn Yang Liwan</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!profile/associates/tsai.html" id="tsai">Tsai Ming Ming</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#!profile/team.html" id="team">team</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">projects</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">featured projects</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HELLO</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">project list</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">current</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#!project/current/all">all</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!project/current/urban">urban</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!project/current/resort">resort</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!project/current/spa">spa</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!project/current/restaurant">restaurant</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!project/current/restaurant">others</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">completed</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">publications</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">books</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">magazines</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">contacts</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="contact_singapore.html">Singapore</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact_milan.html">Milan</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact_beijing.html">Beijing</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>


</div>
```

### CSS

```
#menu ul
{
list-style-type:none;
position:absolute;
padding: 5px 0px;
margin:0px;
width:100px;
}

#menu
{
position:relative;
border-top-color:#afafaf;
border-top-style:solid;
border-top-width: thin;
font-size: 11px;
margin-top:5px;
height:80px;
}

#menu ul ul
{
display:none;
position:absolute;
padding:5px 0px;
left:150px;
top:0px;
height:80px;
}
```

### Javascript (jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#menu ul li a').click(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('current'))
        {
            var relatives = $(this).parent().siblings();
            relatives.find('ul').css('left',150).hide();
            relatives.find('.current').removeClass('current');
            $(this).siblings().animate({'left':'-=20', 'opacity':'toggle'},'slow');
            $(this).addClass('current');
            if($(this).attr("href") != "#"){
            var url = $(this).attr("href").split('#!')[1];
            $('#content').slideUp('slow', function(){$(this).load(url, function(){$(this).slideDown('slow')});})
            window.location = base_url+url;
        }
        }

        $(this).parent().siblings().find('.black').removeClass('black');
        $(this).addClass('black');

        return false;
    });
})
```

[Demo on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3dmQH/3/).

Here is a screenshot: I only want “all”, “urban”, “resort”, and “spa” to appear initially.

[image: Screenshot of menu]

Comment: what value are you setting `overflow-y` to? if you want to clip, you should use `overflow-y: hidden`.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure you can limit the number of elements, but you can set the height and set the overflow to auto, so if it's higher then specified width there will be a scrollbar.

```
            <ul class="inner-ul">
                <li><a href="#!project/current/all">all</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!project/current/urban">urban</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!project/current/resort">resort</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!project/current/spa">spa</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!project/current/restaurant">restaurant</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!project/current/restaurant">others</a></li>
            </ul>

.inner-ul {
  height:50px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: oh wow, it actually works! i think i tried to do something like this, but i put the css at  the wrong element. thank you so much Romario!

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell from the question and fiddle (and I can't see the image) but I think you need

```
overflow-x: auto;
```

Here's a good resource for overflow: http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

Comment: thanks for the reference and helping me edit my post. i'm new here, so I couldn't attach any image yet

Comment: My pleasure @donysukardi.  Welcome to SO!

Comment: If this works, make sure to select it as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Change height to 70px and add "overflow:auto;" to your menu css statement